# Can't add textLabel to a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, textlabel

I have a class file that is a subclass of the `UICollectionViewController` class. In my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, I am trying to set the `textLabel` of the cells. However, there is no `textLabel` option in the completions. This is the method so far:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    // Configure the cell
    cell.backgroundColor = cellColor ? UIColor.blueColor() : UIColor.orangeColor()
    //cell.textLabel.text = "Text"???
    switch indexPath.item {
    case 0...5:
        cellColor = true
    case 6...13:
        cellColor = false
    default:
        cellColor = true
    }
}
```

What can I do to add the `textLabel` to the cells?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike tableViewCell ,UICollectionViewCell doesn't have textLabel. You need to add the UILabel to cell's content view
example:

```
var title = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, 40))
cell.contentView.addSubview(title)
```

Comment: That looks like objective c, which I've never used. Could you convert that into swift?

Comment: Sorry if I'm getting on your nerves-is there any way I can make the text a larger size, horizontally center, and vertically center the label in the cell? Thanks very much.

Comment: It is very basic stuff actually , you really need to have understanding about these basics. You can make your text larger with font property label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 20) you set the size value larger

Comment: one way of centering : title.center = cell.center

Comment: Ok, thank you. I should research more about these font properties.

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 4

Here is the Swift 4 way to add text to a collection view cell:

```
    let title = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.bounds.size.width, height: 40))
    title.textColor = UIColor.black
    title.text = "T"
    title.textAlignment = .center
    cell.contentView.addSubview(title)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the documentation, Luke.  It's under Xcode's "Help" menu.

UICollectionViews don't have textLabels - that's why you don't get a completion.

They have contentViews.  You can put text in the content view though.  Any UIView subclass will do.  If *all* you want is text (no graphics), then you could use a UITextView for your content view, then assign to its "text" property:

cell.contentView.text = "Text"

However, you will want a subclass of UICollectionView that already provides the UITextViews for the contentViews.

Comment: the only 2 Outlets for `UICollectionViewCell` are: `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` in storyboard. Can `contentView` be assigned via storyboard?